# Unable to install eclipse-installer on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: eclipse, jdk

I tried to install by using below instruction:

```
tar xf eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz
cd eclipse-installer
./eclipse-inst
```

But a message came up; I go to details and it shows:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(JceSecurityManager.java:66)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2610)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(Cipher.java:2634)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(CipherSuite.java:602)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(CipherSuite.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(CipherSuite.java:1074)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(SSLContextImpl.java:354)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(SSLContextImpl.java:42)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(SSLContextImpl.java:590)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:292)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1844)
    at java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1820)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:169)
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:99)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLContexts.createSystemDefault(SSLContexts.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransferFactory.newInstance(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransferFactory.java:27)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.internal.provider.filetransfer.Activator.getFileTransfer(Activator.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$InputStreamConnectionHandler.sendConnectionRequest(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1641)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl$ConnectionHandler.process(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:1392)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.ECFURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(ECFURIHandlerImpl.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1269)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.handleArchiveRedirection(SetupCoreUtil.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.configureResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.util.SetupCoreUtil.createResourceSet(SetupCoreUtil.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.SetupWizard.<init>(SetupWizard.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.Installer.<init>(Installer.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.run(InstallerApplication.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.start(InstallerApplication.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:547)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1472)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:118)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can't read cryptographic policy directory: unlimited
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(JceSecurity.java:324)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(JceSecurity.java:73)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:109)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(JceSecurity.java:106)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(JceSecurity.java:105)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: try `sudo ./eclipse-inst`

Answer (score 0):

[It seems you use an Early-Access version of **JDK 9**.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45494304/6505250)

See how to **[configure Eclipse (Installer) for Java 9](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9)** or **[download an Eclipse package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/)** directly instead of using the Eclipse installer.